# How many simultaneous builds can be run on GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to find the maximum number of simultaneous builds that can be run on `GitHub Actions`. By simultaneous builds, I mean builds for different repositories at the same time. There is option to run parallel jobs in a particular build. But I am trying to find out how many such builds can be run parallel? For example `TravisCI` limits parallel builds to 1,2 etc. based on the plan purchased.

Answer (score 0):

got the answer for this!

```
GitHub plan Total concurrent jobs   Maximum concurrent macOS jobs

Free            20                           5

Pro             40                           5

Team            60                          5

Enterprise      180                         50
```

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/usage-limits-billing-and-administration#usage-limits